# MATLAB out of java heap memory when importing a gif

Tags: java, matlab

I'm using MATLAB R2012b 64-bit on a Windows 8.1 machine with 8GB of RAM. I'm trying to import a 6MB gif image in MATLAB using `imread`, when this happens:

```
>> A = imread('nightearth.gif');
   Error using readgif>read_multiframe_gif (line 73)
   Java exception occurred:
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

    at java.awt.image.SampleModel.getPixels(Unknown Source)

    at java.awt.image.Raster.getPixels(Unknown Source)

Error in readgif (line 33)
[X,map] = read_multiframe_gif(filename);
Error in imread (line 434)
    [X, map] = feval(fmt_s.read, filename, extraArgs{:});
```

As suggested by various sources in the MathWorks forums and documentation, I increased the Java heap size in the preferences. This didn't work however; even increasing it to the maximum value of 2014MB doesn't solve the problem. What is going wrong here? I'm puzzled since the gif is just 6MB and the available memory looks more than sufficient.

Comment: try this: -Xms1g -Xmx7g

Comment: Do you have any other variables in your workspace?

Comment: @2cents, the problem happens both with and without other variables in the workspace.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, are those options to feed to `imread`? what's the meaning of them?

Comment: A google search "matlab out of heap java" gave [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/04/26/controlling-the-java-heap-size/) as the top answer. You should try it.